# How to transfer packets from ethernet card to another ethernet card

Tags: networking, ethernet, packet

I have a desktop with two ethernet(etho,eth1) cards and OSSIM installed in it. I have a laptop with webmin installed, where i want to write rules for transferring packets from eth1 to eth0. Both the laptop(10.3.2.25) and desktop(10.3.2.148) are in same network. I am using fedora 17 in my laptop.

Comment: Just follow the [installation guide](https://alienvault.bloomfire.com/posts/525575-installation-guide/public).

Answer (score 0):

I have flushed my iptable and added new rules. OSSIM had its own iptables and i dint use webmin.

```
'iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -i eth0 -d 192.168.10.1 -p TCP -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth1 -s 192.168.10.0 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE 

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT '
```

And it worked out.